# Why is my file download failing?

Tags: c#, asp.net

#### There is another way...

Despite VDWWD's excellent answer about creating a postbacktrigger for the updatepanel, my time crunch forced me to an alternate approach which worked.

So rather than using an `<asp:CommandField>` on the GridView and doing the download on `SelectedIndexChanging`, I went for an `<asp:HyperLinkField>` as below:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField Text="Download" DataNavigateUrlFields="Filename"
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Members/Documents/{0}" Target="_blank" />
```

---

#### Edit 1

Here's the exact error text from chrome dev tools:

> Uncaught Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
>   Details: Error parsing near 'PK

Upon inspection of the HTTP Response in Fiddler, I see that there is no file transfer being attempted, but it looks more like the binary data for the file is being written directly to the response:

[image]

So now the question becomes what have I done wrong and how do I fix it?

---

#### Original Question

It's a simple concept: save the uploaded file to a location and save the file path of the file in the database when uploading.

When downloading, transfer the file from the saved path to the client.

So why isn't it working?

```
protected void gvFiles_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    using (DataModel db = new DataModel())
    {
        var fileId = (Guid)gvFiles.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Values["Id"];
        var file = db.ContractDocuments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == fileId);

        if (file != null)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = file.MimeType;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment; filename={file.Filename}");
            Response.TransmitFile(file.FilePath);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting a parser error in my browser's dev tools... something about *"this can happen when editing the response with response.Write()"*

Annoyingly, when I was reading binary data for the file out of the database for the download (as follows), it worked:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = file.MimeType;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment; filename={file.Filename}");
Response.BinaryWrite(file.FileData);
Response.End();
```

So how does the single changed line break it?

Comment: It looks like you are triggering a download inside an UpdatePanel. If so set a PostBackTrigger to the download button.

Comment: @VDWWD the download is being triggered but inside of a user control which is inside of the update panel on the main page. I'm not sure how th postbacktrigger will work in this case

Comment: The `filename` part of the `content-disposition` header is supposed to be in quotes.  i.e. `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"`

Answer (score 2):

You can add a PostBackTrigger Programatically. In this snippet it loops all the rows in a GridView and add every download button as a Trigger.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvFiles.Rows)
{
    LinkButton lb = row.FindControl("DownLoadButton") as LinkButton;
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(lb);
}
```